# How to hide the description of JUMP made by dll

Tags: c++, assembly

I'm building a dll to make changes to the game and would like to know if anyone knows how to hide the void description.

[image: Void in C++]

[image: Jmp in Assembly]

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to avoid screenshots.

Comment: To your question, what exactly do you want to hide and where? What description? The function name in the resulting assembly?

Comment: If the function is exported by name, export it by ordinal. Strip debug symbols, too.